# Are there now established classes of solar-electric powered spacecraft?

Tags: nasa, terminology, solar-power, electric-propulsion

The NASA.gov press release [NASA Awards Contract to Launch Initial Elements for Lunar Outpost](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-awards-contract-to-launch-initial-elements-for-lunar-outpost) says:

> NASA has selected Space Exploration Technologies (SpaceX) of Hawthorne, California, to provide launch services for the agency’s Power and Propulsion Element (PPE) and Habitation and Logistics Outpost (HALO), the foundational elements of the Gateway. As the first long-term orbiting outpost around the Moon, the Gateway is critical to supporting sustainable astronauts missions under the agency’s Artemis program.
>
> After integration on Earth, the PPE and HALO are targeted to launch together no earlier than May 2024 on a Falcon Heavy rocket from Launch Complex 39A at NASA’s Kennedy Space Center in Florida. The total cost to NASA is approximately $331.8 million, including the launch service and other mission-related costs.
>
> The PPE is a **60-kilowatt class** solar electric propulsion spacecraft that also will provide power, high-speed communications, attitude control, and the capability to move the Gateway to different lunar orbits, providing more access to the Moon’s surface than ever before.

and the idea of classes of spacecraft reminds me a bit of [destroyer classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_destroyer_classes_of_the_United_States_Navy#Cold_War_and_beyond) thought it's a numeric designation rather than named.

**Question:** Are there now established classes of solar-electric powered spacecraft? Or at least *proposed classes?* Or is simply a fancy way to say "roughly 60 kW"?

---

Glossary:

- PPE: Power and Propulsion Element
- HALO: Habitation and Logistics Outpost
- Destroyer: A fast, maneuverable, long-endurance warship (so not a good analogy... yet)

Comment: Re, "established classes," We will need those if we're going to have a proper Space Race.

Comment: "Or is simply a fancy way to say "roughly 60 kW"?" I think this is the answer here.